# FATAL EXCEPTION: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Class is not a View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-manifest

### ISSUE:

I'm getting an eclipse error stating:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML   file line #24: Class is not a View com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity
```

I've copied the source code verbatim from the YouTube API for Android found here:

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/android-player/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/VideoListDemoActivity.java

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

### LOGCAT:

```
  11-21 13:13:52.106: D/ActivityThread(16075): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
11-21 13:13:52.106: D/ActivityThread(16075): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
11-21 13:13:52.106: D/ActivityThread(16075): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
11-21 13:13:52.306: D/AbsListView(16075): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-21 13:13:52.547: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(16075): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
11-21 13:13:52.577: E/(16075): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
11-21 13:13:52.587: E/(16075): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
11-21 13:13:52.597: W/dalvikvm(16075): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41800438)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Class is not a View com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:604)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity$PageAdapter.getView(VideoListDemoActivity.java:292)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2453)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2288)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13957)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13957)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13957)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13957)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13957)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13957)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2003)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1824)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4553)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:1380)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
11-21 13:13:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(16075):    ... 47 more
```

### NOTES:

Line 292 is `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);`

### SOURCE SNIPPET:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = convertView;
      VideoEntry entry = entries.get(position);

      // There are three cases here
      if (view == null) {
        // 1) The view has not yet been created - we need to initialize the YouTubeThumbnailView.
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
        thumbnail.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, thumbnailListener);
      } else {
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(thumbnail);
        if (loader == null) {
          // 2) The view is already created, and is currently being initialized. We store the
          //    current videoId in the tag.
          thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
        } else {
          // 3) The view is already created and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId
          //    on the loader.
          thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
          loader.setVideo(entry.videoId);
        }
      }
      TextView label = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text));
      label.setText(entry.text);
      label.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      return view;
    }
```

### XML LAYOUT: video_list_demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <fragment
      class="com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity$VideoListFragment"
      android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/video_box"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
        android:onClick="onClickClose"/>

    <fragment
        class="com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity$VideoFragment"
        android:id="@+id/video_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

### XML LAYOUT # 2: video_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

  <com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity
      android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/no_thumbnail"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:textColor="#fff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### FULL SOURCE:

```
import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A sample Activity showing how to manage multiple YouTubeThumbnailViews in an adapter for display
 * in a List. When the list items are clicked, the video is played by using a YouTubePlayerFragment.
 * <p>
 * The demo supports custom fullscreen and transitioning between portrait and landscape without
 * rebuffering.
 */


public final class VideoListDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnFullscreenListener {

  /** The duration of the animation sliding up the video in portrait. */
  private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS = 300;
  /** The padding between the video list and the video in landscape orientation. */
  private static final int LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP = 5;

  private VideoListFragment listFragment;
  private VideoFragment videoFragment;

  private View videoBox;
  private View closeButton;

  private boolean isFullscreen;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.video_list_demo);

    listFragment = (VideoListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);
    videoFragment =
        (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);

    videoBox = findViewById(R.id.video_box);
    closeButton = findViewById(R.id.close_button);

    videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    layout();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    layout();
  }

  @Override
  public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
    this.isFullscreen = isFullscreen;

    layout();
  }

  /**
   * Sets up the layout programatically for the three different states. Portrait, landscape or
   * fullscreen+landscape. This has to be done programmatically because we handle the orientation
   * changes ourselves in order to get fluent fullscreen transitions, so the xml layout resources
   * do not get reloaded.
   */
  private void layout() {
    boolean isPortrait =
        getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    listFragment.getView().setVisibility(isFullscreen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    listFragment.setLabelVisibility(isPortrait);
    closeButton.setVisibility(isPortrait ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    if (isFullscreen) {
      videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
      setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
      setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
    } else if (isPortrait) {
      setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
      setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
      setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
    } else {
      videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
      int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
      setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), screenWidth / 4, MATCH_PARENT);
      int videoWidth = screenWidth - screenWidth / 4 - dpToPx(LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP);
      setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT);
      setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT,
          Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    }
  }

  public void onClickClose(@SuppressWarnings("unused") View view) {
    listFragment.getListView().clearChoices();
    listFragment.getListView().requestLayout();
    videoFragment.pause();
    videoBox.animate()
        .translationYBy(videoBox.getHeight())
        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
        });
  }

  /**
   * A fragment that shows a static list of videos.
   */
  public static final class VideoListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final List<VideoEntry> VIDEO_LIST;
    static {
      List<VideoEntry> list = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
      list.add(new VideoEntry("YouTube Collection", "Y_UmWdcTrrc"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Tap", "1KhZKNZO8mQ"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("Chrome Multitask", "UiLSiqyDf4Y"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("Google Fiber", "re0VRK6ouwI"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("Autocompleter", "blB_X38YSxQ"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Motion", "Bu927_ul_X0"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("Translate for Animals", "3I24bSteJpw"));
      VIDEO_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    private PageAdapter adapter;
    private View videoBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      adapter = new PageAdapter(getActivity(), VIDEO_LIST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      videoBox = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.video_box);
      getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
      setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      String videoId = VIDEO_LIST.get(position).videoId;

      VideoFragment videoFragment =
          (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);
      videoFragment.setVideoId(videoId);

      // The videoBox is INVISIBLE if no video was previously selected, so we need to show it now.
      if (videoBox.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
          // Initially translate off the screen so that it can be animated in from below.
          videoBox.setTranslationY(videoBox.getHeight());
        }
        videoBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      // If the fragment is off the screen, we animate it in.
      if (videoBox.getTranslationY() > 0) {
        videoBox.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();

      adapter.releaseLoaders();
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
      adapter.setLabelVisibility(visible);
    }

  }

  /**
   * Adapter for the video list. Manages a set of YouTubeThumbnailViews, including initializing each
   * of them only once and keeping track of the loader of each one. When the ListFragment gets
   * destroyed it releases all the loaders.
   */
  private static final class PageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<VideoEntry> entries;
    private final List<View> entryViews;
    private final Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ThumbnailListener thumbnailListener;

    private boolean labelsVisible;

    public PageAdapter(Context context, List<VideoEntry> entries) {
      this.entries = entries;

      entryViews = new ArrayList<View>();
      thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = new HashMap<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader>();
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      thumbnailListener = new ThumbnailListener();

      labelsVisible = true;
    }

    public void releaseLoaders() {
      for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
        loader.release();
      }
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
      labelsVisible = visible;
      for (View view : entryViews) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public VideoEntry getItem(int position) {
      return entries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = convertView;
      VideoEntry entry = entries.get(position);

      // There are three cases here
      if (view == null) {
        // 1) The view has not yet been created - we need to initialize the YouTubeThumbnailView.
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
        thumbnail.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, thumbnailListener);
      } else {
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(thumbnail);
        if (loader == null) {
          // 2) The view is already created, and is currently being initialized. We store the
          //    current videoId in the tag.
          thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
        } else {
          // 3) The view is already created and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId
          //    on the loader.
          thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
          loader.setVideo(entry.videoId);
        }
      }
      TextView label = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text));
      label.setText(entry.text);
      label.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      return view;
    }

    private final class ThumbnailListener implements
        YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener,
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

      @Override
      public void onInitializationSuccess(
          YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
        loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
        thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.put(view, loader);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
        String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
        loader.setVideo(videoId);
      }

      @Override
      public void onInitializationFailure(
          YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult loader) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
      }

      @Override
      public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView view, String videoId) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView view, ErrorReason errorReason) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
      }
    }

  }

  public static final class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment
      implements OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private String videoId;

    public static VideoFragment newInstance() {
      return new VideoFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      if (player != null) {
        player.release();
      }
      super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
      if (videoId != null && !videoId.equals(this.videoId)) {
        this.videoId = videoId;
        if (player != null) {
          player.cueVideo(videoId);
        }
      }
    }

    public void pause() {
      if (player != null) {
        player.pause();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean restored) {
      this.player = player;
      player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
      player.setOnFullscreenListener((VideoListDemoActivity) getActivity());
      if (!restored && videoId != null) {
        player.cueVideo(videoId);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
      this.player = null;
    }

  }

  private static final class VideoEntry {
    private final String text;
    private final String videoId;

    public VideoEntry(String text, String videoId) {
      this.text = text;
      this.videoId = videoId;
    }
  }

  // Utility methods for layouting.

  private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
  }

  private static void setLayoutSize(View view, int width, int height) {
    LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
  }

  private static void setLayoutSizeAndGravity(View view, int width, int height, int gravity) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    params.gravity = gravity;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
  }

}
```

Comment: May you add the code of your activity com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity. Which class does it extends ?

Comment: It looks like the error is with the `layout` file you use in `VideoListDemoActivity`. Post that. And you shouldn't be adding your `fragmnets` to the `manifest`.

Comment: Updated (shown above) : )

Comment: Thanks! I removed the fragment from my manifest...

Comment: Post `getView()` of `VideoListDemoActivity` and indicate line 292. That's where the error is coming from

Comment: Updated : ) [thanks!] - line 292 is: view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);

Comment: See anything I might be able to fix in there? (I'm stumped.)

Comment: Is `VideoListDemoActivity` an extension of `Activity`?  `Activities` can't be used as `Views`.

Comment: Yes - I believe so: public final class VideoListDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnFullscreenListener { 


(I posted my full source above just now if you'd like to see it)

Comment: Any suggestions as to how I might create a fix? It's setup as an activity in the YouTube API for Android - which I copied this from verbatim: https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/android-player/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/VideoListDemoActivity.java

Comment: It isn't setup as a view in the original source from google: https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/android-player/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/VideoListDemoActivity.java ...any idea how I can customize it to work?

Comment: Does it work to instantiate a fragment as an inner class of an activity? Haven't seen that before.

Comment: It does not seem to work (as is) It is crashing... any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
com.example.idg2.VideoListDemoActivity
```

In your layout isn't referring to a Fragment. Activities in layouts do not make sense. Change it to the `Fragment` class you expect to see in the view.

Comment: Should I remove it or replace it with something else?